# List of notable materials from 2017-2019 of software dev in the space industry

Tags: software

I was looking for relevant books about the development of software in space tech.

I've had a hard time looking for ***recent*** information about software so I'll appreciate any tip -like key words, or terminology- to look for articles or any material that explain this field. I said space tech because I want to have an overview of this technologies and find which one is attractive for me.

I'm a software engineer student. Thanks in advace!

Comment: You may be interested in my answer to [What does the software quality process for NASA's SLS look like?](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31443/18663) I describe some of what the software development processes for a complex man-rated space system looks like

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it's my first question so I'm trying to explain what I'm looking for. I change some things to be more specific, the thing is that I don't know where to start... I've searching in Google but the information is not that specific. So, I'm trying to know what "key words" or a book that helps me have context of the terminology used in software and space exploration and then I'll get better results

Comment: @TanyaGonzález Looks good, I've reopened, as the list of notable* materials from 2017-2019 should be pretty manageable. * (Notable may need a little bit more clarification, but we can work on that if necessary. IMO, not an obstacle to reopening.)

Comment: As you're new to stackexchange, for *recent* info try the column at right titled "Related."  You'd be surprised how relevant those Q&A's often are.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll follow your tips

Answer (score 2):

For European p.o.v. you could try opening an account to ECSS (ecss.nl), it requires you to create an account. It's not very recent.. but it's still current, and still applied (whether good or bad). There's some online discussion of how to adapt to processes to agile approaches.

Comment: The info in the target time frame is extremely limited.

Comment: Private companies in the "new space" category don't publish their software development methodologies, and from my knowledge, most of them don't have one. Either they are too small to put effort into it, or what they have is proprietary information. A low-cost high-quality software development methodology is part of their competitive advantage and they wouldn't just give it away. I've seen that insurance companies sometimes prefer if software has been developed in compliance with a SW quality standard.

Answer (score 1):

This is a community repository. Feel free to add additional resources here:

- European Cooperation for Space Standardization, ECSS (ecss.nl)

  It requires you to create an account. It's not very recent.. but it's still current, and still applied (whether good or bad). There's some online discussion of how to adapt to processes to agile approaches.